# Meaning of NOT all but finitely often

Tags: notation, definition

Can someone clarify for me the meaning of the statement "NOT all but finitely often"?

It's driving me crazy. I'm not able to break it up.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, almost every tag I tried required at least 300 reputation.

Comment: hint: try defining a collection of finite, countable sets.

Comment: "all but finitely often" means "there is a finite set $K$ of cases where something (call it condition $P$ to give it a name) is satisfied in its complement". The negation of this would be "There is no finite set $K$ of cases such that $P$ is satisfied in the complement of $K$". The latter can be further translated to "$P$ is not satisfied in an infinite set of cases".

Comment: For example, the function $n^2-100$ is positive in the natural numbers *all but finitely often*. In fact, it is positive except for $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$. For the complement of $K=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ it is positive.

Comment: For example, the function $(-1)^n$ is NOT positive in the natural numbers *all but finitely many often*. In fact, it is negative for $n=1,3,5,7,9,...$ for all odd inputs. There are infinitely many exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A property holds for "all but finitely many $x$" is the set of $x$ on which it fails is finite.

The negation of the above is: the set  on which the property fails is infinite. In other words, it fails infinitely often.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase *not all but finitely often* means *for some set* $A$ *and property* $P(x)$, *it is not the case that* $P(x)$ *holds for all* $x \in A$, *but for some finite set* $B \subseteq A$, *it is the case that* $P(x)$ *holds for all* $x \in B$. In order to demonstrate that $P(x)$ holds for not all $x \in A$ but only many $x \in A$, you must show that $P(x)$ is *false* for some $x \in A$ but *true* for some finite subset of $A$ (which may be empty).

A trivial example of a property $P(n)$ and set $A$ for which $P(n)$ holds of only finitely many $x \in A$ is $P(n) \equiv n < 5$ and $A = \mathbb{N}$. Clearly $P(n)$ fails for all $n \geq 5$, so $P(n)$ fails to hold for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. However, $P(n)$ holds for the finite set $B = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : n < 5\}$, so $P(n)$ is true for *not all but only finitely many* natural numbers.

Another example is $P(n) \equiv \int x^n \neq x^{n + 1}/(n + 1) + C$ and $A = \mathbb{N}$. Clearly, $P(n)$ fails whenever $n \neq -1$, so $P(n)$ is not true for all natural numbers $n$. However, $P(n)$ is true whenever $n = -1$, since $\int x^{-1} = \log|x| + C$. Thus, the set of natural numbers for which $P(n)$ is true is finite. So $P(n)$ holds of *not all but only finitely* many natural numbers.